# How to resolve CORS issue while requesting data from API using jquery AJAX and JAVA Backend

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, api

I am building a front-end to show data fetched from API. The API is created with JAVA and Swagger.io by android engineer. Though the API is not authenticated yet but we are planning to include authentication using headers (appID, version, empID and token).

I am struggling to resolve the CORS issue in this API call. When I send request without any headers I get the result but when I do the same with headers (as specified above) I get this error

`OPTIONS

   buyer.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://some-
   dummy-link.com/fetchAreaCode. 
   Response to preflight request doesn't 
   pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is

   present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8081' is 
   therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.`

These headers are set on server side :

```
resp.setContentType("application/json");
resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-
With, Content-Type, Accept, appID, empID, version, token");
resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, 
OPTIONS, HEAD");
```

I know the issue is with preflight OPTIONS request. I have tried adding headers in doOptions servlet but no luck

My client side code is this:

```
$.ajax({
         method: "GET",
         url: url,
         data: parameters,
         headers : 
           "appID" : "8",
           "version" : "3",
           "empID": localStorage.empID,
           "token" : localStorage.accessToken,
         beforeSend : beforeSend,
         complete : complete,
         success: newCallback,
         error: onRequestFailure
     });
```

I am calling another API from some another domain which is working fine, so the issue might be on server side only.

UPDATE :

When using 'contentType : 'application/json' in jquery AJAX method I get this

```
OPTIONS  
buyer.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://some-
dummy-link.com/fetchAreaCode. 
Response to preflight request doesn't 
pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is  
present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8081' is 
therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

Comment: `I have tried adding headers in doOptions servlet but no luck` - what does this mean? is `doOptions` something that handles `OPTIONS` request?

Comment: are using MVC API

Comment: No idea (the one who developed API is an android engineer)

Comment: @JaromandaX Don't know. I came across this while searching on stackoverflow

Comment: It worked, added headers in doOptions, doPost and doGet servlets and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

[enter link description here][1] Hi, Go there and look javascript panel. There I was put my server side example and ajax method.

```
  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/npathak56/ct5myj08/
```

Comment: I have told the backend engineer to make the necessary changes as suggested by you. The backend is being deployed will let you know the outcome as soon as it is deployed.